# how to get memory used by any process programatically in vC++ in windows mobile

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, windows-mobile

I tried to get memory used by a individual process by using

```
BOOL WINAPI GetProcessMemoryInfo(
  __in   HANDLE Process,
  __out  PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS ppsmemCounters,
  __in   DWORD cb
);
```

But it is showing error saying `undeclared identifier in PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS`. I have included the header-file `"psapi.h"`.

Anyone please suggest any API.

Thanks, M

Comment: `GetProcessMemoryInfo` is not a Windows Mobile or Windows CE SDK function, it's for the desktop.

Comment: then what is an approprite api for windows mobile??

Answer (score 4):

`GetProcessMemoryInfo` is not a Windows Mobile or Windows CE SDK function, it's for the desktop. You'll need to use the ToolHelp API functions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915058.aspx) to get a process memory snapshot and also the undocumented `CeGetProcVMInfo` from pkfuncs.h.

More to read here:

- http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/123149/How-to-get-individual-process-memory-usage-statist.aspx
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vssmartdevicesnative/thread/e16a2a74-2181-4c73-bfce-37bd601717ff